# Can't access overlay's components

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I am trying to make a custom camera using **UIImagePickerController()**. I have followed [this](https://makeapppie.com/2015/11/04/how-to-make-xib-based-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-cameras-in-swift/) tutorial and it is really easy to follow. But the problem is,when I try to change the overlay's shootButton's text,or image from **viewDidLoad()/any other method** of **ViewController** rather than **didShoot(overlayView:CustomOverlayView)**, I can't change it.It doesn't give any errors,but doesn't change either. Here is what I tried to change the text or image -

```
    picker = UIImagePickerController() //make a clean controller
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    picker.showsCameraControls = false
    picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.on
    //customView stuff
    let customViewController = CustomOverlayViewController(
        nibName:"CustomOverlayViewController",
        bundle: nil
    )

    let customView:CustomOverlayView = customViewController.view as! CustomOverlayView

    customView.frame = self.picker.view.layer.frame

    customView.shootButton.setTitle("Changed", for: UIControlState.normal)

    customView.shootButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "changedbutton"), for: .normal)

    customView.delegate = self
```

Can anyone help me on this? I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was when I was trying to change any text or image, I was creating another CustomOverlayView reference and a new picker. So when I was changing any text or image,it was changing but it didn't show as previous picker was still on the view. Using one picker and one CustomOverlayView reference did the trick.